# How to make my list of widget scrollable?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Thank you for checking my issue:
I have a list of widget (List) that i am trying to put in a `SingleChildScrollView` widget, but when i do, it's not scrollable anymore, i have made a small reproduction of my problem on Codepen:
https://codepen.io/blkkkbvsik/pen/GRZKzxJ

I can make my list scrollable by wrapping my `SingleChildScrollView` with an `Expanded` but it ruin my layout (See screenshot)

This is with the `Expanded` widget, it ruin my layout:
[image: Without Expanded]

This is how it is supposed to look, but the list is not scrollable anymore:
[image: Without Expanded]

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the SingleChildScrollView with a Flexible widget instead of Expanded?

Comment: @AdarshBalu That was actually EXACTLY what i needed to do. Thank you so much for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working Code :

`Flexible (child: SingleChildScrollView())`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ListView` instead of a `Column` and wrap it with `Expanded` like this..

```
Expanded(
    child: ListView(
        children: art,
    ),
)
```

*Edit:*

For space above and below this widget in the main `Column`, we can use `SizedBox`s with a certain height above and below it like..

```
const SizedBox(height: 30),
Expanded(
    child: ListView(
        children: art,
    ),
),
const SizedBox(height: 30),
```

Comment: It's actually working but it broke my layout too, I have the same result as the first screenshot

Comment: For maintaining the spacing between the other children, you can add a `SizedBox()` of a certain height above and below this `Expanded` widget.